# gradients using only html and css and javascript?

Tags: gradient

Is there a way to do gradients in css/html/javascript only that will work across all the major browsers? (MS IE 5+, Firefox, Opera, Safari)?

Edit: I would like to do this for backgrounds (header, main panel, side panels). Also, would like to have vertical line gradients as well.

Edit: after reading the responses, let's open this up to Javascript solutions as well, since HTML/CSS by itself makes it tougher to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this before as a gimmick, using javascript like:

```
var parent = document.getElementByID('foo');
for(var i=0; i< count; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.width='100%';
    div.style.height = 1/count+"%";
    div.style.top = i/count+"%";
    div.style.zIndex = -1;
    parent.appendChild(div);
}
```

If your requirement is just to have a gradient, you really should use a gradient image set as background-image in css. In my case, I was animating the colors and position of the gradient as well. I can't vouch for now cross-browser it is (for starters, make sure the parent has some position applied, otherwise it won't be a position-container for the absolute positioning.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unclear on the implementation details you are seeking (such as background, or just a border along the side of the window, etc); however, it's possible albeit a little tedious.

One example that comes to mind would be to have n-block level elements, such as divs, and then give them each a small height (a couple of pixels, for example) and then gradually change the background color of each subsequent element.

Comment: The problem with approaches like this is that they fundamentally mix up the structure and the presentation.

Comment: Yeah, I don't disagree with you. I just don't know of any other options that simply use HTML/CSS and work across all A-browsers.

Comment: depending on how the implementation looks like, if it works across all A-browsers, mixing up structure and presentation while not ideal, i would consider versus creating images in photoshop.

do u have any examples using html/css i could experiment with?

Comment: Further more using div's etc to create a background probably end up gobbling more bandwidth than an image itself...

Comment: It would not consume much bandwidth if you did it in script, as I would definitely recommend.

Comment: JavaScript is my ideal solution, as well - it'd be a really simple iteration. joshjdevl mentioned only HTML/CSS. I was trying to stay true to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I use the gradient CSS code generator by colorzilla: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

It has polyfills for IE - but not sure how far back it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is no.

You can create something that looks like a gradient using only css, but to then use it like an image background... I think that is pushing it a bit.

**EDIT (feeling silly)**

I found the solution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to create a gradient now. 
1. You can create image for it.
2. Use CSS3 Gradient, it can be linear, radial and repeating.

Syntax for linear :

```
linear-gradient: ([angle | to ] ,[ [color-stop], [color-stop]+);
```

Syntax for radial :

```
linear-gradient: ([angle | to ] ,[ [color-stop], [color-stop]+);
```

For IE6 to IE 9 we can use the filter property or you can also use [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

Following are some referances that will help:

[Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

[CSS3File](http://www.css3files.com/gradient/)